# C# ApiController returns List but postman shows "Could not get any response"

Tags: c#, request, httpclient, asp.net-apicontroller

I am struggling with strange situation. I am calling void method to ApiController from postMan but I get strange results. ApiController captures request and returns result with 3 objects but postman somehow shows that could not get any respone.. While all other methods which return one value works fine problem accours then returning multiple objects.

ApiController:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/documents/AllDocs/")]
public List<Document> AllDocs()
{
    lock (_lock)
    {
        _documentsRepository = DocumentsRepository.Instance;
        var result = _documentsRepository.GetDocuments();

        return result;
    }
}
```

Documents repository:

```
public List<Document> GetDocuments()
{
    var documents = new List<Document>();
    try
    {
        var db = new Context();
        var docs = db.Document;
            //.Include(x => x.DocumentItems)
            //.Include(x => x.Page.Select(y => y.RegionCropper.Select(z => z.Cropper)))
            //.Include(x => x.Page.Select(y => y.RegionCropper.Select(z => z.MinorCropper))).ToList();
        return docs.ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return documents;
    }
}
```

PostMan :

[image]

WebConfig :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    private static HttpSelfHostServer _server;

    public static void Run(string port)
    {
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration($"http://localhost:{port}");//"http://localhost:8080");

        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "API Default",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //    "newdocument", "api/documents/newdocument/{document}",new { document = RouteParameter.Optional });


        config.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;;
        config.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
        _server.OpenAsync();

    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _server?.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try without the last slash `[Route("api/documents/AllDocs")]` ?

Comment: @rene it has nothing to do with slash becouse method is called and returns values.

Comment: What kind of ApiController is this? Have you tried returning an ActionResult?

Comment: @Alex I added webconfig. No I didn't but other methods which returns one object works fine so should this method. So why to change return type?

Comment: @Chris Everything is on local machine from postman every method except this one returns as needed but problem accours then it api returns result multiple objects. Everything explained in the header please read it first.

Comment: is `Document` a DB model? maybe it has serialization issues?

Comment: @Ridiculous yes it is DB model converted to List. What kind of issues could it have?

Comment: Is List appropriate here? maybe you should try adding a simpler method that just returns an int or string and confirm that works.

Comment: @pmcilreavy then i return one object everything works fine.

Comment: A whole range of issues... It could hold a reference to the DB connection, or other objects, maybe attempt to read from the DB when accessing properties... Try to return a list of strings, and if that works, create a new DTO class to represent a document and return a list of those (filling them with data yourself).

Comment: @BenSin please Document[] instead of List<Document>.

Comment: Thank you all for struggle I found sollution to serialize list to json and return Actionresult.

Answer (score 4):

It's a shot in the dark, but I lately faced the same problem.

I had an issue with my JSON-Config.

In my model I had a class `User` with a List of `Postings`:

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public List<Posting> Postings{ get; set; }
}
```

The model of those Postings looked like that:

```
public class Posting
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostingDate { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I returned a `List<Posting>` Postman said could not get any response.

The problem here was the Json-serialization. When trying to serialize my Model, Json faced an self refferencing loop, but didn't threw an exception.

The only thing I had to do to get rid of this is adding [] to the User in my Posting Model:

```
[JsonIgnore] 
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

I relazied that would to the trick when I tried to serialize the List programatically, because that way the exception was thrown.

Comment: But how can you Serialize it to return the children to the client instead of just cutting of the data of the child?

Comment: Im not sure if I got your question right, but if you are serializing an user-object and Include the postings, there is not data cut of.